# Converting Images to USDZ Format for Websites

Tags: javascript, python, html, usdz

I'm a beginner when it comes to HTML and websites, but I've recently been experimenting with Python to convert images into STL format successfully. However, I'm facing a challenge when it comes to integrating the STL file into a website. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to the functionality found on the website https://imagetostl.com/, but instead of generating STL files, I want to convert images into USDZ format.

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to tackle this problem. Here's a brief overview of what I've accomplished so far:

I've managed to convert images to STL format using Python.

However, I'm unsure how to effectively embed the resulting STL file into a website.

My ultimate goal is to convert images into USDZ format, on a website.

If anyone has experience working with USDZ conversion or integrating 3D files into websites, I would love to hear your insights. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding:

The process of converting images to USDZ format.

How to effectively embed USDZ files into a website.

Any recommended libraries, tools, or tutorials that can simplify this process.

Thank you so much in advance for your help and support. I'm eager to learn and explore this exciting field further!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out [this library](https://products.aspose.com/3d/python-net/conversion/stl-to-usd/) for converting STL to USDZ (note: the library is compatible with Python versions >=3.5, <3.11, so you may need to downgrade).

For the 2nd part of this answer, I will assume that by "embedding," you mean that you want to prompt users to download the STL/USDZ file from your website. You can create a button that accomplishes this with the following HTML code:

```html
<button onclick="prompt_download()">Click me!</button>
<script>
function prompt_download() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/file");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
      alert("Download failed!");
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

First, we create a button that triggers a javascript function (`prompt_download`) when clicked (`onclick=`). This function uses XHR (XML HTTP Request) to make a request for the file's URI (`/path/to/file`) so that the user doesn't have to leave the page. The function will also monitor if the download fails (where we check `xhr.status !== 200`).

I see that you are new to stack overflow, so feel free to reply to this answer with a comment and we can work things out if my suggestions do not fully answer your question.

Comment: Yeah I tried to download that library but it doesn't work for some reason. on top of that, that's only working with a free trial right? 3999 dollars is just not in my price range. and for the second part, by embedding that I mean just to have an usdz file in the html code, because previewing that shouldn't be a problem. So i want the usdz bc it looks good in the preview, the users dont need to download it.